# Basic query about chain functions

Tags: javascript

Pretty basic question but, in a case like this...

`const myVariable = GenericObject.myMethod().brand.toUpperCase()`

what would the `.brand` be referring to...i.e. how does this 'chain function' actually fit together?

You can assume `myMethod` returns an empty object.

Thanks

Comment: it looks like `brand` is a string. but it can't be, since its an empty object so it will be `undefined`.

Comment: brand looks like a property of myMethod. It could be scoped to GenericObject though

Comment: If `myMethod()` returns an empty object then the code will throw an exception and not work.

Comment: If `myMethod` returns an empty object then `brand` will be undefined. `myMethod` would have to return an object with a `brand` property for this to work. Assuming `myMethod` does *not* return an empty object then `brand` would most likely be a string given the next method being called but technically there's no way to know for sure what exactly `brand` is without more context.

Comment: myMethod need to return an object which is having  brand as an attribute in it. Chain function means response of one will be the input for other

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys...it's proven very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like this

```js
function GenericObject() { }

GenericObject.myMethod = function () {
    return {
        brand: 'string'
    };
}

console.log(GenericObject.myMethod().brand.toUpperCase());
```

Or

```js
var GenericObject = {
    myMethod: function () {
        return {
            brand: 'string'
        };
    }
};

console.log(GenericObject.myMethod().brand.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments gave you the short answer:

`brand` refers to what was returned from `myMethod()`. if it's an empty object it will have trouble finding property `brand` in it.

you can read more about chaining [here](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html). It's a simple and clear explanation with examples (and not very long).